# Convert from string with leading zeros to bigint in SQL Server CE isn't working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact (3.5) database with a `nvarchar` column with lots of data that looks like `000000000011070876`. I'm trying to copy that data to another column that is a `BIGINT`, using the `CONVERT` function.

My first try was:

```
UPDATE Mobile_Reservation 
SET SAPNo = CONVERT(BIGINT, ItemNumber)
```

If I run this query in SQL Server 2008 R2, it works fine. `000000000011070876` becomes `11070876`. Unfortunately, in SQL Server CE, it becomes 0. Apparently it cannot handle the leading zeros. But it will turn `000000004000010576` into 40, which I assumed meant it was only looking at the first 10 digits. Then I tried:

```
UPDATE Mobile_Reservation 
SET SAPNo = CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(ItemNumber, 8, 10))
```

With a start index of 8, I assumed it would start just before the 4 (The first 8 digits are always 0s, but may be more than 8 0s). This worked somewhat better, but not successfully. `000000000011070876` became 1107 and `000000004000010576` became 40000105.

Then I tried the hardcoded string:

```
UPDATE Mobile_Reservation 
SET SAPNo = CONVERT(BIGINT, '4000010576')
```

And this worked fine, which confused me even more. I tried a few different combinations of strings, and the logic it seems to use is: **for every leading 0 in the string, a char from the other end is removed**. '1234' becomes 1234, but '01234' becomes 123. But it's not a hard fast rule, because 04000010576 becomes 40000105, which means the single leading 0 is removing two digits from the end...

Is this a problem with SQL Server CE's implementation of `CONVERT`, or perhaps something else I'm not noticing? Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I noticed in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450(v=sql.110).aspx) that convert on nvarchar can impose a 30 character maximum.  This kind of jives with your observation that every left-padding 0 chops a character off the right -- what is the size of your nvarchar field?  Is it only 18?  or something bigger.  Documentation on [update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174122.aspx) mentions that nchar fields can be padded to their defined length -- which is a weird thing to say -- but I wonder if some under the hood string manipulations are messing you up.

Comment: @Greenspark That's certainly a good thought, there's definitely something strange happening under the hood.. If I have some time I might take a look at the SQL CE library to see how the actual Convert function is handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up solving this problem with:

```
UPDATE Mobile_Reservation 
SET SAPNo = CONVERT(BIGINT, REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(ItemNumber, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'))
```

Not the nicest solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit conversion between bigint and nvarchar() -- what about just trying

```
UPDATE Mobile_Reservation SET SAPNo = ItemNumber
```

If not that, then sometimes you also can get away with something like

```
UPDATE Mobile_Reservation SET SAPNo = 0 + ItemNumber
```

I'm sorry I don't have SQL CE to test on.

Comment: Unfortunately SQL CE is considerably less.. nice than full SQL Server. The implicit conversions fail in the same way