# Removing leading zeros from a string in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-ce

I have a string representing a batch number of goods, for example "0000AZA001B". I only need the "AZA001B" part. How can I achieve that in SQL Compact?

Comment: My text "0000AZA001B" and result???? "AZA001B"

Answer (score 6):

Use the following syntax to trim an unknown number of leading zeros:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(BatchNumber, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

This replaces all zeros in your string with spaces, uses the `LTRIM` function to trim leading spaces and converts the spaces back into zeros.

Answer (score 1):

There is so many way to do this..check this example and links.

```
declare @str varchar(50) = '0000AZA001B'

select 
    @str , 
    substring(@str, patindex('%[^0]%',@str), 10),
    REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(@str, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

[Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement)

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/trimming-leading-zeros

**Updated as SQL Compact version**
Try this :

```
select CONVERT(BIGINT, REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('000000000011070876', '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'))
```

[Convert from string with leading zeros to bigint in SQL Server CE isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745902/convert-from-string-with-leading-zeros-to-bigint-in-sql-server-ce-isnt-working)

Still you want further analyze, you can download this tool :- 
https://sqlcequery.codeplex.com/