# Removing leading zeros from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have removed all leading Zeros in my column but what if the same column has a space its replaced by '0'.. Example: batch number has 000123, 0000145 but when the column has 'CO PO' its filled with 0.. o/p is **CO0PO**.. how do i fix this?

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(COMPANYCODE, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

[Removing leading zeros from a string in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379337/removing-leading-zeros-from-a-string-in-sql-server-2008-r2/72013137#72013137)

Comment: you are replacing chars.
check TRIM function
SELECT TRIM( '.,! ' FROM  '     #     test    .') AS Result;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Why not just cast to a numerical data type, numbers don't have leading zeroes. Or, better yet, store your numerical data *as* a numerical data type.

Comment: @PowerMouse: NOTE: this does not work with LTRIM.   When the original string is `00001230` you want to end with `1230` i think ?

Comment: @Luuk , LTRIM/RTRIM just trimming spaces. But it depends on SQL version , there is a function TRIM was introduced in SQL 2017.
also, as my understanding , column contains mixed context.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 SUBSTRING(COMPANYCODE, 
    PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', COMPANYCODE + ' '), 
    LEN(COMPANYCODE)
  ) as COMPANY_CODE
FROM TABLE1
```

This solved my issue in removing leading zeros. Example:my `companycode` column had 000123, 0000145,CO PO for which my initial `LTRIM` function converted it as 123,145 and CO0PO...

When i used this one it changed perfectly to 123, 145, CO PO

Answer (score 0):

in 2017 SQL was introduced function TRIM
please check example (I didn't understand if you need to keep PO/CO)

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(10) = 'PO 000127'

SELECT 
    TRIM('0 ' FROM @x) AS Result,
    CASE 
        WHEN @x like '%PO%' THEN 'PO ' + TRIM('0 ' FROM SUBSTRING(@x, 3, LEN(@x)))
        WHEN @x like '%CO%' THEN 'CO ' + TRIM('0 ' FROM SUBSTRING(@x, 3, LEN(@x)))
    ELSE TRIM('0 ' FROM @x)
    END AS Result2
```

UPDATED answer, after conversation with @luuke i am giving you a adjusted solution

```
SELECT 
CAST(
    CASE 
        WHEN @x like '%PO%' THEN REPLACE(@x, 'PO', '')
        WHEN @x like '%PO%' THEN REPLACE(@x, 'PO', '')
    ELSE RTRIM(LTRIM(@x))
    END 
    AS BIGINT) AS result
```

Comment: `select trim('0 ' from '000001230 ');`   (Output is `123`, and not `1230`)

Comment: again, which SQL server version you have?
run this command: SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
it should be 140;
if you have SQL 2017+ version and compatablility level is lower check with DBA's if you can adjust it:ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140

Comment: `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases` returns 150 (on my system)

Comment: @luuk, i see you point, it removes trailing zerow also, in this case it would be complex string manipulation, probably with charindex etc... i updated answer